# Django's send_email() does not raise BadHeaderError when testing

Tags: python, django, email

I am writing some tests for a contact-email view and I find that BadHeaderError is not raised when I use fake email settings (EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD). In production it works as expected, being successful when I configure email properly and raising the exception when I use a fake email. Tests are always successful, no matter what email settings I use.

I have tried to use DEBUG=False to run the tests but got the same output. I have no idea about what could be causing this behaviour.

This is the view I am testing (I have it simplified here, the rest of the code is just about getting POST data and validating it, which work as expected):

```
# home.views.py

def contact(request):
    success = False
    error = ''
    try:
        email_message = (
        "MESSAGE SENT BY: " +
        contact_email + " (" +
        contact_name + ")"
        "\n_______________________________"
        "_________________________________"
        "__\n\n\n" +
        contact_message
        )
        send_mail(
            contact_subject,
            email_message,
            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
           [settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL]
        )
        success = True
    except BadHeaderError:
        error = (
            "Invalid header found."
        )
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        error = (
             "A connection error occurred and "
             "your message has not been sent."
        )
    response = {'success': success, 'error': error}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response),
                        content_type='application/json')
```

UPDATE - These are the tests finally working as expected, thanks to @mata comments and my own research with the mock library:

```
class ContactTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_contact_ok(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("home:contact"),
            {
                'contactName': 'John Snow',
                'contactEmail': 'johnsnow@winterfell.com',
                'contactSubject': 'Winter is coming',
                'contactMessage': 'Hello',
                'contactCaptcha': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_TEST_KEY
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['success'], True
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['error'], ''
        )

    @mock.patch("home.views.send_mail")
    def test_contact_ko_bad_header(self, send_mail_mock):
        send_mail_mock.side_effect = BadHeaderError()
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("home:contact"),
            {
                'contactName': 'John Snow',
                'contactEmail': 'johnsnow@winterfell.com',
                'contactSubject': 'Winter is coming',
                'contactMessage': 'Hello',
                'contactCaptcha': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_TEST_KEY
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['success'], False
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['error'],
            'Invalid header found.'
        )

    @mock.patch("home.views.send_mail")
    def test_contact_ko_smtp_error(self, send_mail_mock):
        send_mail_mock.side_effect = smtplib.SMTPException()
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("home:contact"),
            {
                'contactName': 'John Snow',
                'contactEmail': 'johnsnow@winterfell.com',
                'contactSubject': 'Winter is coming',
                'contactMessage': 'Hello',
                'contactCaptcha': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_TEST_KEY
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['success'], False
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['error'],
            'A connection error occurred and your message has not been sent.'
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a test session the test runner [sets up](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2425f6fda099a2134dbf72c8a30270cc9a659f1e/django/test/runner.py#L398) a local memory backend (by calling [`django.test.utils.setup_test_environment()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2085d8d5bc2625076983d3be14b30ea684c3f0d5/django/test/utils.py#L95)), which will simply append sent mails to `mail.outbox` instead of really sending them, therefore changing your email user and password settings won't have an effect.

Also, invalid user and password settings shouldn't generate a BadHeaderError, that's only used when a header contains newline or carriage return characters.

Comment: So is there a way to test if emails are really going to be sent? I am thinking of using mocks to fake that behaviour, raising different exceptions.

Thanks also for the `BadHeaderError` comment, I guess I should be also catching `smtplib.SMTPException` for general fails.

Comment: That sounds like you want to test the email backend, not the view. `django.mail.get_connection(backend='django.core.mail.backends.EmailBackend')` would give you a connection explicitly using the smtp backend, which you then can use in a testcase as the `connection` argument to `send_message`.

Comment: I got it finally working as I wanted, isolating my view and replacing `send_mail()` behaviour with mocks. I have updated the tests in the question with the right ones, in case you (or anyone) are interested in my approach. Thank you for the help, I was really frustrated before knowing `send_mail()` had a different behaviour in tests.